# Magento event logging not showing all events

Tags: magento

I added this line to /app/Mage.php under the function dispatchEvent($name, $data), just above the return statement:

```
 Mage::log($name, null, 'events.log');
```

However,  my events.log only shows 3 different events:

```
2013-02-13T21:46:21+00:00 DEBUG (7): resource_get_tablename
2013-02-13T21:46:21+00:00 DEBUG (7): core_collection_abstract_load_before
2013-02-13T21:46:21+00:00 DEBUG (7): core_collection_abstract_load_after
```

These three are just repeated over and over. No other event names ever show up. Does this mean the other events aren't firing somehow?

Comment: where did you insert your log? there are minimum two dispatchEvent methods `\Mage::dispatchEvent` and `\Mage_Core_Model_App::dispatchEvent` But to answer your question. No, there should be a lot more events - depending on the site you are requesting.

Comment: Take a look @ http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153/where-can-i-find-a-complete-list-of-magento-events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution. With the line of code in question, in the file and function in question, with the setting in System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Log Settings > Enable Logging set to "No",  I only get the three events, listed in the question, outputted to the log file.

If I set that setting you "Yes",  I then get every event that gets fired.   This seems like an "obvious answer to a dumb question",   but since I hard coded the logging code into the function that handles events,  I don't see how the logging setting matters.  Why would dispatchEvent() get completely different inputs depending on a logging setting?  Wouldn't it need the name of the event regardless of a logging setting?   But alas, I'm fairly new to Magento and don't yet quite fully understand the ideas inside of it.

One additional thing I found:  With that one Mage:log line of code added,  whenever I save settings in configuration,  the page 500's, though, the settings DO get saved.  I'm not so worried about this.

**TL;DR**:  set "Enable Logging" to "Yes" under System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Log Settings, on top of adding the line of code to dispatchEvent().